# wget timeout on Let'Encrypt certificate server

Tags: ssl, wget, centos-7, letsencrypt

I'am on a CentOS server trying to understand why I cannot connect to another website that is exposing a **Let'sEncrypt R3** issued certificate.

```
#  cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
```

If I try a wget command, it ends up in a timeout.

```
# wget --no-proxy --no-dns-cache --no-check-certificate https://oidc.7shield.eu:32644
--2021-10-15 10:45:05--  https://oidc.7shield.eu:32644/
Resolving oidc.7shield.eu (oidc.7shield.eu)... 51.68.92.220
Connecting to oidc.7shield.eu (oidc.7shield.eu)|51.68.92.220|:32644...
......................................................................
```

I also tried to add directly the website PEM certificate under

```
/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
```

and did

```
update-ca-trust
```

according to this [article](https://www.sbarjatiya.com/notes_wiki/index.php/CentOS_7.x_add_ca_or_host_certificate_as_trusted_certificate_at_OS_level), but nothing changed.

This problem is also affecting an application running on a network bridge inside
a Docker `openjdk:8-jre-alpine`.

How to make connection work to the above website, on the whole system?
How can I debug it? wget -d doesn't seem to show anything relevant.

**Update**

Using openssl on the server I get:

```
# openssl s_client -connect oidc.7shield.eu:32644
socket: Bad file descriptor
connect:errno=9
```

while when running the command locally I get something more interesting about the problem:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect oidc.7shield.eu:32644
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 CN = oidc.7shield.eu
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = oidc.7shield.eu
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = oidc.7shield.eu
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = oidc.7shield.eu

issuer=C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = R3

---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
CN = oidc.7shield.eu
Client Certificate Types: ECDSA sign, RSA sign, DSA sign
Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA512:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:DSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA224:DSA+SHA224:ECDSA+SHA1:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA1
Shared Requested Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA512:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA-PSS+SHA256:RSA-PSS+SHA384:RSA-PSS+SHA512:RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:DSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA224:RSA+SHA224:DSA+SHA224
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1856 bytes and written 412 bytes
Verification error: unable to verify the first certificate
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: B0A7CBC3721AE5A83B11D5DAABC0530CC9AF202B79B27DF100EB6341EF2EAEDA
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 783E822EE7D4504083595A4C4315F411EB0D9761F08D8C7323EFE191FFF0A6B9FEF4F5162E5D33800FD8AA29D2740576
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1634289721
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
    Extended master secret: yes
---
read:errno=0
```

Comment: Does wget show a certificate error? If not, then what made you decide that the certificate is the problem?

Comment: I was able to resolve this connection issue locally in a Java application by importing the Let'Encrypt certificates in the `keystore`. The error was `PKIX path building failed...` Also `openssl s_client -connect oidc.7shield.eu:32644 `shows some inconsistencies in the exposed certificate.

Comment: But none of that is shown in your post?

Comment: None of the information in your question indicates this is a problem with TLS. Instead, everything points at you not being able to connect on a TCP level.

Comment: Please see the updates on the question's body

Comment: It may also be a set of problems. Locally it was enough to trust the certificate of the website from the Java Keystore. Maybe on the server there is also a firewall? problem. I'm open to debug suggestions.

Comment: @DanielB The fact is that the problem is just fro this website because I able to wget other urls